# Select on primary key regardless of column name?

Tags: mysql

I'm just wondering if there's any way to select a row using the primary key in the `WHERE` clause without necessarily knowing the name of the key's column.

My suggested PHP function is as follows:

```
function getData($table,$key,$asarray=false) {
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from `".$table."` where primary='".$key."'");
    if( !$asarray) return mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $ret = [];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) $ret[] = $row;
    return $ret;
}
```

*A few notes:*

1. `$table` only ever comes from literal strings inside the code, never from an outside source.
2. For the purposes of this question, assume that `$key` is already properly escaped.
3. I don't care that `mysql` is deprecated in PHP 5.5, because I'm using PHP 5.4
4. For that same reason `$ret = []` is a perfectly valid way to define an array - I say this because in my last question people were telling me my code wasn't working because of this syntax.

Now, my current, actual, working code has an associative array mapping table names to their corresponding primary key field names. I'm just wondering if there's an automated way to do this, preferably one that doesn't involve querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or `SHOW INDEXES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no automated way of doing it without knowing or querying the primary key column(s).

*Note that the primary key may be more than one column!*

I implemented this sort of generic find-by-primary-key method in the Zend Framework 1.0.  We had to write code for the table gateway class to discover the table's primary key and all other columns.

Use `DESC` as a faster alternative to `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  The `SHOW` commands just map to queries against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, and that can have a high cost because it triggers InnoDB tables to re-read a portion of the tables to refresh in-memory statistics ([unless you set innodb_stats_on_metadata=0](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/)).

Answer (score 2):

It would require another call to the mysql server, but this should get you what you're looking for:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Zend Framework 1 for this sort of thing.

Just do a find() from a Zend_Db_Table object and pass the key(s) you want like this:

```
$table = new Zend_Db_Table($table);
$rows = $table->find($key);
```

Comment: Thank you ;) I should add that with Zend_Db metadata cache, it's pretty awesome.